# How to Encode UI Objects in Xcode (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, decode, encode

My program crashes whenever I try to encode a tuple containing UI objects. I get an (lldb) crash on the AppDelegate (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT)

I've attempted commenting out the tuple and it works fine.

```
convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    if let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String,
       let grid = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "grid") as? [[Letter]],
       let userGrid = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userGrid") as? [[(UIView, UITextField, UILabel)]] {
        self.init(name: name, grid: grid, userGrid: userGrid)    
    } else {
        return nil         
    }
```

Can anyone offer up any suggestions?

Comment: Don't attempt to encode views. Encode data instead. Recreate the views from the data.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by encoding a view? What underlying problem are you trying to solve?